# ComputedProperty (ndb Datastore) equivalent in Firestore native mode

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

We currently have a database on ndb Datastore in Google App Engine (python 2.7 standard). we are planning to migrate to Firestore native mode. There is a feature [ComputedProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#computed) in ndb - do we have anything similar to this in Firestore Native mode?

Comment: Are you migrating because you want to get off of Python 2 or to use the Native mode features? If it's the former, consider  [ndb for python 3](https://github.com/googleapis/python-ndb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Firestore in Native mode doesn't directly support something like computed properties. You would instead use a client-site transaction or a Cloud Function, see for example [aggregation queries](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/aggregation).